# SAML ADFS SSO Websphere Liberty SP initiated

Tags: saml-2.0, websphere-liberty

I have done the following steps in my plain web application.

1. `<feature>samlWeb-2.0</feature>` in server.xml
2. `<samlWebSso20 id="defaultSP"></samlWebSso20>` in server.xml
3. Retrieved metatdata file using the url https://ip:sport/ibm/saml20/defaultSP/samlmetadata
4. Got the metadata file from ADFS and placed in `resources/security`
5. ADFS admin is to configure my metadata file in ADFS

What next? How to configure redirecting to ADFS from my app? How to parse the ADFS response and allow the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the configurations, Liberty will automatically start the SSO flow when unauthenticated user access secured web resource in Liberty. Liberty first create a signed SAML authnRequest based on the metadata from ADFS, redirect user to ADFS, user login to ADFS, ADFS generates a SAML response, and redirect user back to Liberty. Liberty uses NameID as principal, be sure to setup ADFS to emit NameId (by default, ADFS does not include NameID in SAML response).
Here is the link to Liberty document, and you only need follow first two steps to get it working, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_config_saml_web_sso.html

Comment: Ok. Will do NameID. Is there anything to configure with web application or home page.

Comment: How does the Liberty identify secured web resource? As securing a particular url can be done programmatically as well.

Comment: NameID will be available as a session variable so that I can check for authenticity for a particular URL?

Comment: In order to trigger authentication, you either define authorization constraints in web.xml, or use role annotation.

Comment: Liberty uses NameID to construct principal name